Ardupilot SITL (ArduCopter) - is it possible to move the vehicle to desired Lat\Lon?
Is it possible to set position of simulated vehicle in such way that will move the vehicle almost instantly, without simulating it actually flying there? Distance between current and desired locations can be in kilometers.
I've found parameters like SIM_OPOS_LNG but setting them to other values does not change anything.
So I'd like to know if it is possible. And if it is, how to achieve this effect? It should be a solution that is easy to automate with c++ or python, because these desirable new locations come from a process at it's runtime and should be managed in scope of a couple of seconds.
If you know a better place to ask this kind of questions, please redirect me there.
